# Analytical derivation of 2D Fourier transform for radial symmetric function

Tags: fourier-transform

I am trying to understand the connection between the 2D Fourier and Hankel transform in a [book](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Natalie-Baddour/publication/241069465_Two-Dimensional_Fourier_Transforms_in_Polar_Coordinates/links/59db6ecaa6fdcc0ffd1a9f72/Two-Dimensional-Fourier-Transforms-in-Polar-Coordinates.pdf). In the meantime, I came across the following derivations:

> In the polar coordinate, the 2D Fourier transform can be written as
> $$F(\rho, \psi)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(r,\theta)e^{-ir\rho\cos(\psi-\theta)}r drd\theta $$

which can be easily shown by the change of variables. However, the question comes up in the following. The book says, if we assume that the function is radially symmetric ($f(r,\theta)=f(r)$), then the Fourier transform can be written as:

> $$F(\rho, \psi) = \int_{0}^{\infty} rf(r) dr \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-ir\rho\cos(\psi-\theta)} d\theta$$

Why can we separate the two integrals even though the second integrand is also a function of $r$?

Comment: This is still understood to be a nested/iterated integral.  It's somewhat standard notation in physics, although usually I'd keep the differential attached to the integral signs.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this notation can also be a nested integral! Thanks! It's really confusing for beginners like me...

Comment: As **march** writes, it's more common, and in my opinion better, to write
$$
F(\rho, \psi) = \int_{0}^{\infty} dr \, rf(r) \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{-ir\rho\cos(\psi-\theta)}
$$
This makes $\int_a^b dx \, u(x)$ look like an operator $\int dx$ acting on the expression $u(x).$

Comment: Thank you @md2perpe. Yeah, your notation looks much clearer to me.

Comment: This answer might help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2730751/fourier-transform-of-radially-symmetric-functions-references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered by @march and @md2perpe.

The notation actually represents a nested integral, which is also described by the following notation:
$$F(\rho,\psi)=\int_0^\infty dr \ r f(r) \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\theta \ e^{-ir\rho\cos(\psi-\theta)} $$