# D-dimensional Fourier transform of $\exp{(-c|\vec{x}|^\alpha})$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, special-functions

Prove that for $\vec{x},\vec{\xi} \in \mathbb{R}^D$, $\mathbb{R} \ni c, \alpha = \mathrm{const.}$ the $D$-dimensional Fourier transform of $ f(\vec{x}) = \exp{(-c|\vec{x}|^\alpha})$
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(\vec{\xi}) = \int \exp{(-c|\vec{x}|^\alpha}) e^{-i\vec{\xi} \cdot \vec{x}} \, d^D \vec{x}
\end{equation}
can be transformed into the integral over just one variable $x = |\vec{x}|$
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(\xi) = (2\pi)^{D/2} \xi^{1-D/2} \int_0^\infty J_{D/2 - 1} (\xi x) x^{D/2} \exp{(-cx^\alpha)} \, dx
\end{equation}
where $\xi = |\vec{\xi}|$ and $J_\nu$ is a Bessel function. Are hyperspherical coordinates of use here? Maybe the integral definition of the Bessel function
\begin{equation}
J_\nu(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \exp{[i(\nu t - x \sin t)]} \, dt
\end{equation} is useful for the proof. I am thankful for any ideas.

Edit: I now noticed that this integral definition cannot be used here since it is only defined for integer values of $\nu$, whereas $D/2 -1$ is a multiple of 1/2 so it can be a rational value.

Comment: Related (although only in 2 dimensions): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2741952/168433

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is rotation symmetric, so is $\hat f$. Therefore we can use a fixed $\vec\xi$; lets take $\vec\xi=(0,\ldots,0,\xi).$

Then, to parameterize the space, we start with writing $\vec x = r\vec n,$ where $r=|\vec x|$ and $\vec n\in S^{D-1},$ the unit sphere in $D$-dimensional space. Then we parameterize $S^{D-1}$ by $n_D=\cos\theta$ and $(n_1,\ldots,n_{D-1})=\sin\theta\ \vec\nu,$ where now $\vec\nu\in S^{D-2},$ the unit sphere in $(D-1)$-dimensional space, and $\theta\in[0,\pi].$ Our parameterization of the space thus is
$$
(x_1,\ldots,x_{D-1},x_D)=(r\sin\theta\ \nu_1,\ldots,r\sin\theta\ \nu_{D-1}, r\cos\theta).
$$

With this parameterization the volume element becomes
$d^D\vec x = r^{D-1}\sin^{D-2}\theta \, dr \, d\theta \, d\omega,$
where $d\omega$ is the surface measure on $D^{D-2}.$

Thus,
$$
\hat{f}(\vec{\xi}) 
= \int e^{-c|\vec{x}|^\alpha} e^{-i\vec{\xi} \cdot \vec{x}} \, d^D \vec{x}
= \int_{r=0}^\infty \int_{\theta=0}^\pi \int_{\vec\nu\in S^{D-2}} e^{-cr^\alpha} e^{-i\xi r\cos\theta} \, r^{D-1}\sin^{D-2}\theta \, dr \, d\theta \, d\omega(\vec\nu).
$$

Since the integrand has no dependency on $\vec n$ the integral over that variable can be extracted and we get
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(\vec{\xi}) 
&= \omega(S^{D-2}) \int_{r=0}^\infty \int_{\theta=0}^\pi e^{-cr^\alpha} e^{-i\xi r\cos\theta} \, r^{D-1}\sin^{D-2}\theta \, dr \, d\theta \\
&= \omega(S^{D-2}) \int_{0}^\infty  e^{-cr^\alpha} r^{D-1} \left(\int_{0}^\pi e^{-i\xi r\cos\theta} \, \sin^{D-2}\theta \, d\theta \right) \, dr,
\end{align}
$$
where $\omega(S^{D-2})$ is the total surface size of $S^{D-2}.$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since posting the question I have also arrived at the last line of your derivation. I guess now I have to find a suitable substitution to bring it to the form of the integral definition of the Bessel function, but I'm still thinking about it. Alternatively I have found a derivation using a series expansion in terms of spherical harmonics which leads to the desired end result, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform#Relation_to_the_multidimensional_Fourier_transform

Comment: So far I have tried a few things but I did not mangage to solve it yet. If you have an idea on how to continue could you maybe give me a hint towards the correct substitution to make (or maybe something else entirely if I'm on the wrong path). I would be very thankful.

Comment: @PascalS. Have you found a solution? I'm thinking about deleting my answer since it doesn't solve the hard part.

Comment: So far sadly not but I am still working on it in the mean time. I think I will try solving it for some values of $D$ to see if a pattern arises. That might be helpful. I think you should leave ur answer up. It is still helpful. It is more formal and better explained than my version of it :)

Comment: I found a formula that might be useful: [Jacobi-Anger's relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion).